# Is there any data query library for Javascript?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jqgrid

I saw the searching > complex search demo on http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html and really liked the advanced search box which has powerful query-based search very close to Excel. I want to reuse this advanced query interface for other applications and purposes instead of jqgrid. Is it possible to reuse it to query external json data without going through jqgrid? I don't know how jqgrid build it so I'm wondering if it is some built-in jquery UI search module or plugin that i'm not aware of. Thanks in advance if you can offer some tips.

Answer (score 0):

It you like

**XPath**

JSONPath: http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

**jQuery**

jfunk http://code.google.com/p/jfunk/

**CSS**

jsonselect http://jsonselect.org

**LINQ**

linq.js http://linqjs.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

You might also like

- [Dollar Q](https://github.com/furf/dollar-q): has a chaining syntax (like jQuery).
- [SpahQL](http://angryamoeba.co.uk/spahql-announce/): similar syntax to XPath ([Homepage](http://danski.github.com/spahql/), [Github](https://github.com/danski/spahql)
- [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/): also XPath like, but with a more javascript-y flavour.